# MRPT: Is is possible to get an image from a viewport?

Tags: c++

I am trying to simulate a simple scene with a camera that moves around. If I create another viewport I can manipulate the viewport's camera and move it around the scene.

How can I extract a CImage after the viewport renders all the objects in the scene.

Thanks in advance

**Upload 2**

I am using windows and getting gray images from getLastWindowImage

I have also tried the offscreen rendering approach but it also returns a gray image. My goal is to simulate a camera attached to a robot and process the returned image to extract features and detect objects.

Currently I have a DisplayWindow3d with my scene and for now just trying to get the image from the default viewport.

```
            mrpt::opengl::COpenGLScenePtr &theScene = vis->get3DSceneAndLock();
            vis->unlockAccess3DScene();
            //Create a rendered
            mrpt::opengl::CFBORender render(800,600);
            //Create an image 
            mrpt::utils::CImage frame(800, 600, 3, false);
            render.getFrame2(*(theScene.pointer()), frame);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like:

```
mrpt::gui::CDisplayWindow3D  win;
//... fill your 3D scene

while (win.isOpen())
{
  // Start capturing:
  win.captureImagesStart();

  // Get screenshot:
  mrpt::utils::CImage img;
  bool capture_ok = win.getLastWindowImage(img);

  // Do whatever to img


  // Loop
  mrpt::system::sleep(1);
}
```

However, note that some Windows themes may make the image capture fail, giving gray images... Google for some solution online or, use the alternative off-screen rendering method (see [sample code](https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/blob/master/samples/offscreen-render/test.cpp)).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I've tried both methods but still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Then it must be a bug in wxWidgets wxGLCanvas... 
Please, if you want to nail down the problem, open a ticket against wxWidgets bug tracker, explaining the problem and pointing them that the code used to capture images is around line 204 in: https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/blob/master/libs/gui/src/CDisplayWindow3D.cpp#L204
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies, I'll open a ticket with wxWidgets. However I am wondering why the CFBORender  experiences the same problem. Did I set up rendering the scene correctly and am I correct to assume I can render the same scene in a window and using CFBORender ? I looked at the CFBORender.cpp and it appears not to rely on wxWidgets but only opengl.

Comment: This bug has been fixed now in MRPT by not using wxWidgets to grab the image, but directly accessing the OpenGL buffer pixels. 
See this commit: https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/commit/53189fee2bb160c004f148691b7e50aa386ba40a
The fix will be included in the next 1.4.0 stable release, in the meanwhile you can use the latest version from the git `master` branch.